# What are the sizes in pixels of a mobile ad banner for android

Tags: android, banner

I think that the size of android mobile ad banners is 320x50 dip (density independent pixels).

So, if I want to design 4 banners (for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi), what are the sizes in pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Admob you just need to create one 640x100 banner (they call it a HD banner) and they will scale it smaller as needed. This way it looks best.

Comment: That simple? Did you try that?

Comment: But this means, that it can't be an animated gif? I assume Android can't resize an animated gif?

Comment: Yes this is what I have done for my games. They have some other options, as you could go check out. But each Advertiser has their own specifics and advantages. The .gif question is a interesting one. I honestly don't know. It has a preview function on their website where you can check both version, the scaled and the original.